# How to insert some number of parentheses into an expression to get smallest integer result?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Assume that I have an expression like this (without evaluating)

```
expr = 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10
```

You can insert some number of parentheses into the expression above to create a valid mathematical expression. 
What would be the smallest possible integer value of the expression and the expression in that case?

Here are some examples of inserting parentheses.

[image]

[image]

The smallest possible integer number is 7 but I wonder if anyone knows some way to solve it with Mathematica. 
 The brute force inserting all possible paranthesises probably works but I don't know how many possible cases in order to do a for loop.

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested?

Comment: @lericr yes, it can be any thing as long as it's mathematical valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Groupings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings) with an inactivated [`Divide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divide) to do this:

```
g = Groupings[Range[10], Inactive[Divide] -> 2];
```

Then, use [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate) to get the values:

```
v = Activate[g];
```

Finally, the min integer can be found from:

```
min = Min[Select[IntegerQ] @ v]
```

> 7

The groupings that produce 7 are:

```
Column @ Pick[g, v, 7] //TeXForm
```

> $
> \begin{array}{l}
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/8)/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/8)/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/8)))/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7))/8)/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6))/7/8)/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/4)/5/6/7/8)/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5))/6/7/8)/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/(8/9))/10)) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/(8/9))))/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7/(8/9/10)))) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7))/(8/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/7)/8/9)/10) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6))/7/(8/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/4)/5/6/7/(8/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5))/6/7/(8/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8))/9)/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8/9)))/10) \\
>  1/(2/3)/(4/5/6/7/8)/9/10 \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/5)/6/(7/8/9)/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6))/(7/8/9)/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8/9)/10))) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8/(9/10))))) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/7)/8/(9/10))) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8))/(9/10))) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6/7))/(8/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5/6))/7/(8/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/(3/4)/5/6/7/(8/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/(3/(4/5))/6/7/(8/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/3)/(4/5/6/7/(8/9))/10 \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/5)/6/(7/8/(9/10))) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6))/(7/8/(9/10))) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/5)/6/7)/8/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6))/7)/8/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/7)))/8/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/7)/8))/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/5)/6/(7/8))/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6/(7/8))))/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/(4/(5/6))/(7/8))/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/4)/(5/6/7)/8/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/4)/(5/6/(7/8))/(9/10) \\
>  1/(2/3)/(4/5/6/7/(8/9/10)) \\
>  1/(2/3/4)/(5/6/(7/8/9)/10) \\
>  1/(2/3/4)/(5/6/(7/8/(9/10))) \\
>  1/2/3/4/5/(6/7/8/9/10) \\
> \end{array}
> $

Comment: Very nice, elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Do integer partititons of 10 (total 42 of them).

```
IntegerPartitions[10]
```

> ```
> {{10}, {9, 1}, {8, 2}, {8, 1, 1}, {7, 3}, {7, 2, 1}, {7, 1, 1, 1}, {6,
>    4}, {6, 3, 1}, {6, 2, 2}, {6, 2, 1, 1}, {6, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 
>   5}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 1, 1, 
>   1}, {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 3, 
>   2, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1}, {4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 
>   1, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 
>   2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2,
>    2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Divide is not commutative, so find permutations:

```
parts = Flatten[(Permutations[#, {Length@#}] & /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[10]), 1]
```

Use `TakeList` to divide into partitions.

```
expr2 = TakeList[Range[10], #] & /@ parts
```

Within each brace, `Fold` using `Divide`.

```
expr3 = Map[Fold[Divide, #] &, expr2, {-2}]
```

Fold again to get the final list:

```
expr4 = Fold[Divide, #] & /@ expr3


Cases[expr4, _Integer]
```

> ```
> {907200, 100800, 9072, 100800, 6300, 1008, 6300, 11200, 56700, 112, \
> 1008, 6300, 252, 63, 252, 14175, 36288, 4032, 63, 252, 175, 567, \
> 2268, 4032, 63, 252, 7, 7, 25200, 175, 1575, 2800, 7, 1008, 1575, \
> 2800, 112, 175, 700, 1575, 7, 7, 63, 112, 175, 7, 252, 28, 448, 28, \
> 28, 567, 63, 7, 63}
> ```

---

**EDIT**

Responding to the OP's comment, the positions of integers in the final lists can be found along with the partititions that generated these:

```
pos = Position[expr4, _Integer]

Transpose@{Extract[parts, pos], Extract[expr4, pos]} // 
 Multicolumn[#, 4] &
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I still read to understand the code but the result looks comprehensive. 
Also it is possible to see the position of parentheses?

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach, somewhere between brute force and simple reasoning. What is the effect of the parentheses? Based on normal order of operations:

a/b/c/d    ->   a/(b c d)

x/(a/b/c/d)    ->    (x b c d)/a

So, with parentheses we have an easy way to flip a term from denominator to numerator (and vice versa). This suggests we can start with a problem that might be simpler: how to segregate the numbers 1..10 into numerator and denominator to produce the desired value? Choosing numerator and denominator elements is just a choice function, and so the number of ways to make this choice is 2^10. But the integer 1 is redundant, and looking ahead, we see that 1 must always be in the numerator. There is also no freedom for 2--it must always be in the denominator. So there are only 2^8 ways to do this. Familiarity with Pick suggests it might be useful to work with binary digit patterns, and so we might represent all of these choices this way:

```
numDenomPickers = 
  IntegerDigits[#, 2] &[Range[2^9, 2^9 + 255]]; 
Short@numDenomPickers
(*{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},<<252>>,{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}*)
```

We can segregate them with this function:

```
SplitNumsDenoms[pickPattern_]:=
  With[
    {range=Range[Length@pickPattern]},(*a generalization to handle different ranges*)
    {Pick[range,pickPattern,1],Pick[range,pickPattern,0]}]
```

Here's a test:

```
SplitNumsDenoms[{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(*{{1, 4, 5, 7}, {2, 3, 6, 8, 9}}*)
```

We want them in order, so we'll need to keep track of their assignment. We could wrap them in identifying heads. Making them listable is just a convenience to simplify the function a bit.

```
SetAttributes[{Num,Denom},Listable];
NumsDenomsOrdered[pickPattern_]:=
  SortBy[
    Flatten@MapAt[Denom,MapAt[Num,SplitNumsDenoms[pickPattern],1],-1],
    First]
```

A quick test:

```
NumsDenomsOrdered[{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(*{Num[1], Denom[2], Denom[3], Num[4], Num[5], Denom[6], Num[7], Denom[8], Denom[9]}*)
```

Based on our observation above, we should parenthesize any sequence that starts with a denominator item and has numerator items following.

```
NumsDenomsOrderedGrouped[pickPattern_] :=
  SequenceReplace[
    NumsDenomsOrdered[pickPattern], 
    group : {_Denom, __Num} :> List @@ group]
```

And:

```
NumsDenomsOrderedGrouped[{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(*{Num[1], Denom[2], {Denom[3], Num[4], Num[5]}, {Denom[6], Num[7]}, Denom[8], Denom[9]}*)
```

Now all we need to do is remove the wrappers. The resulting structure directly shows us the parenthesization we need.

```
GroupedDivisionSequence[pickPattern_] := 
  NumsDenomsOrderedGrouped[pickPattern] /. {Num -> Identity, Denom -> Identity}
```

And:

```
GroupedDivisionSequence[{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(*{1, 2, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}, 8, 9}*)
```

We need a way to evaluate the value of this expression

```
ParenGroupValue[ints__?NumericQ] := Fold[Divide, {ints}];
ParenGroupValue[list_List] := list /. List -> ParenGroupValue
```

Test:

```
ParenGroupValue@GroupedDivisionSequence[{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(*35/648*)
```

And a quick check:

```
1/2/(3/4/5)/(6/7)/8/9
(*35/648*)
```

Now we can find what we're looking for:

```
integerPickers = 
  Select[
    numDenomPickers, 
    IntegerQ[ParenGroupValue@GroupedDivisionSequence[#]] &];
Short[integerPickers]
(*{{1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},<<30>>,{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}*)
```

...

```
minimalIntegerPickers = 
  MinimalBy[integerPickers, ParenGroupValue@*GroupedDivisionSequence]
(*{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}}*)
```

What is the minimal integer value?

```
ParenGroupValue@*GroupedDivisionSequence /@ minimalIntegerPickers
(*{7, 7, 7}*)
```

What are the associated parenthesizations?

```
GroupedDivisionSequence /@ minimalIntegerPickers
(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 9, 10}, {1, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, 8, {9, 10}}}*)
```

Thoughts:
This approach does not consider nested parentheses. As it turns out, nested parentheses are redundant in terms of producing values for the fraction, but it might be interesting to try to find all possible parenthesizations for the minimal value.
What this approach does allow us to find is the minimal number of parentheses we need. In our particular case, we only needed one grouping. This can be found by inspection of the above results, but one could write a function to select the minimal grouping.